# Can't commit changes to GitHub in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, github

I'm pretty new to programming, and I'm having an incredibly difficult time making GitHub and Visual Studio Community 2015 play nice with each other. Usually the first commit goes well, and I can see it on GitHub.com just fine. But it never lets me make any more commits. I make changes to the file, save it, but the commit button in VS stays grayed out. I've been all over the Team Explorer to figure out what I'm doing wrong, and I can't figure it out. It says I have no unpublished changes or anything, even though I'm changing tons of things in the file.

Is there any reason it would stop working after the first commit?

Comment: Normally the commit button stays grayed out until you write a commit message. Did you try to write a commit message?

Comment: Yep! I always write a message. The first commit goes fine: the button activates, I click it. Then I make some changes to the file, save it, and write another commit message. Button stays grayed out.

Comment: Another problem is, whenever I try to create a NEW repository, it asks for the URL of the GitHub one I'm connecting to. So I enter it in (I get it from GitHit, the .git URL) and then Visual Studio says "Can't publish because the repository with that name is not empty." News to me! It doesn't even have a readme in it. Are the commit and new repository problems related? Am I an idiot?

Comment: Are you still using Visual Studio 2015?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I figured it out, and as predicted, I'm an idiot. I was accidentally saving the files OUTSIDE the local repo folder. If anyone else has this problem, make sure you are saving things in the right places. Also, cloning the remote repo instead of trying to create two in each place helped a lot.

Answer (score 6):

1. Close VS
2. Open the particular `.sln` file from the repo

This worked for me.

Answer (score 4):

You would need to add your username and email in you global configuration. Then you will be able to see the commit button enabled.

Answer (score 3):

I had to add username and mail in VS to activate the commit button. The visual studio message telling me to add the data only appeared after a restart of VS. Maybe this will help someone else.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Try to use git push on git shell, the console will tell you if there are any errors, and give you searchable errors.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a local database file, then you will not be able to copy/move the database file, and so any change in the solution cannot be committed. You have either to close the database service, close the connection inside the application or to close the solution and do the commit.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem, and I solved it by using the command line to do my first commit (`git commit -am "Comments"`).  You probably need to use the VS Command Prompt or make sure git.exe can be found in your PATH if you're using cmd.  I installed git separately and used MINGW64. After that, the button was enabled.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the reason was related to the warning on "Configure your username and email".
Initially, I clicked "Configure" link in the warning message and checked the globally-save option and save. And the warning message stayed and commit button remained disabled. When I save it with the checkbox unchecked, finally the warning message went away and the commit button enabled.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you have configured the login information in Visual Studio. I had the same issue and had to configure the login information before committing the changes. This ensures that the login details are authenticated when connecting with the git repository. You can set up these details in the git settings within visual studio. Once configured, Commit All button will be enable.

Answer (score 0):

You may need to authenticate to git before push, if you see its disabled.